# How do I display an arbitrary string inside a datePicker component?

Tags: opus-ui

I'd like to display a string inside a datePicker (for example 'Please select your date of birth'). Once the user has selected a date, this string should no longer show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly stated, the datePicker component only allows dates to be in its value. There are various ways around this, like rendering an extra component over the datePicker. A more efficient way to do it is to render a CSS Pseudo Element over the datePicker component and then hide it once a value has been chosen:

```
{
    "type": "datePicker",
    "prps": {
        "popoverZIndex": 2,
        "position": "relative",
        "hasSelectedValue": false,
        "style": {
            ".cpnDatePicker": {
                "&:after": {
                    "content": "'YYYY-MM-DD'",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "left": "0px",
                    "top": "8px",
                    "z-index": 1,
                    "pointer-events": "none"
                },
                "input": {
                    "visibility": "hidden"
                }
            }
        },
        "scps": [
            {
                "id": "sDP",
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "event": "onStateChange",
                        "match": [
                            {
                                "operator": "isFalsy",
                                "value": "{{sDP.state.self.hasSelectedValue}}"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "setMultiState",
                        "value": {
                            "hasSelectedValue": true,
                            "style": {}
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```